# ffmpeg hflip command causes video to go black

Tags: video, ffmpeg, frames

Using the command `ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]hflip" new.mp4` makes the output video turn completely black in windows media player until you play the file a second time and then frames will be missing.

If you append the mirrored video after another video it will just simply stop playing once it reaches the time in the timeline where the mirrored video starts. If you put the mirrored video before another video it will simply display the mirrored video as a black screen.

Any suggestions on how to fix this or another solution i can use in C# to flip and merge videos?

Comment: Show full console output.

Comment: Why do you use WMP instead of ffplay/VLC for judging your output? Do you have 100% cpu when WMP shows black/drops frames?

Comment: here is the full output: https://imgur.com/a/HO0Cd For some reason it worked playing the entire video this time without problem but other times it doesn't with the exact same file and command. My cpu is not running anywhere close to 100.

I tried running the command 'ffmpeg -i new.mp4 -i test.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]concat;[0]hflip" new3.mp4' and the second video won't play, wmp just restarts from the beginning(second video is not filpped)

Comment: In your 2nd command, the flipped video isn't attached to the main one. It should be `ffmpeg -i new.mp4 -i test.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]hflip[m];[m][1]concat" new3.mp4`

Comment: That solved one of the problems. It seems like the file plays fine in other media players other than wmp for some reason.